# Do individual instances of C++ std::string use the same allocator?

Tags: c++, stl, memory-management

One thing I've always wondered about is if the instances of `std::string` that I use in my C++ code use the same allocator or do they have their own separate memory pools?

Obviously sharing a single memory pool across multiple, frequently created and destroyed strings is more efficient. Can anyone confirm or deny this for me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, they all use `std::allocator`, which uses standard memory routines to get free heap blocks. There is no pooling involved on this layer.

(However, most heap implementations use a dedicated low-fragmentation heap to serve small allocations, and strings are most likely to fall into this category. But this is implementation dependent and not exclusive to or optimized for `std::string`s ...).

Comment: Thanks, that's along the lines of what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

different instances of c++ use the same allocator if you don't specify one. You perhaps are referring to string interning that is standard in java/python etc. If so, no. There is no 'standard' facility for that. However it is easy to add if frequent create/destroy is an issue

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: different instances of the same allocator, but as of C++03, all instances of a given allocator type are equivalent, that is should be capable to deallocate memory allocated by another of them. This usually means that they in fact allocate and deallocate from the same place. This change in C++0x.